# UIToolbar disappears after iAd is dismissed

Tags: iphone, ios6, iad

On UIViewController updating UIImage View and UITextView based on NSTimer. On the same UIViewController showing iAd and right below iAd have UIToolbar. When clicking on iAd and then dismissing it, UIToolbar on UIViewController disappears. Any one knows what is the cause?

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {

 [super viewDidLoad];

 float _gap = 1;

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_gap
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(onTimer)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:NO];




_adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 380, 320, 25)];
_adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
_adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
_adView.delegate=self;
self.bannerIsVisible=YES;
 [self.view addSubview:_adView];
 }

-(void) onTimer {

if  (index < [textArray count])
{

    self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

    index++;

    thisTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.70 target:self selector:@selector(ViewTiming) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}else{

   // index = 0;

    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}}

-(void)ViewTiming{

if (index == 1) {



    self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

    index++;


   aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.55 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}}

-(void)Second{
if (index == 2){

    self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

    index++;


    aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.80 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}}

-(void)Third{

if (index == 3){

    self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

    index++;


     aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.95 target:self selector:@selector(Fourth) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}}

-(void)Fourth{

if (index == 4){

    self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

    index++;


    aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.00 target:self selector:@selector(Fifth) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}}

 -(void)Fifth{

if (index == 5){

    self.textView.text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.imageView.image = [self.imagesArray objectAtIndex:index];

    index++;


    aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.00 target:self selector:@selector(Sixth) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

in viewDidLoad

May be that will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what exactly solved my problem. It was easy one.